# Add texture to part of 3d object and then output whole object

Tags: object, blender

I have .obj file of truck where I want to assign a texture to tyres.
I am doing this in blender:

1. select the vertices/faces of tyres
2. split it into different object (using P)
3. assign a texture file to the new object
4. combine the new object back to the main object using Ctrl+J

The problem is the texture file is not preserved and the whole model is assigned one of the texture files.
How can I assign the texture to just tyres?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new separate material and select the vertices of the tire,
then click 'Assign' to assign that new material to the selected vertices.

[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqpk5.png)

Comment: The shared results are using the similar steps you have mentioned. The problem is that the new material does get assigned to the whole object file instead of just the selected vertices.